# Form not validating onsubmit

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I ma trying to validate the id fields of the following html form on submit. For some reason its not calling  to the JavaScript validation and submitting the form as it is.I am new to JavaScript so its difficult to make out what mistake I am making. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src ="/javascripts/idcheck.js" >  </script>

</head>
<body>

<div class=page>
  <div class=metanav>
  <a href="<% menu_url %>">Menu</a>
  <% IF not session.logged_in %>
     <a href="<% login_url %>">login</a>                          
  <% ELSE %>
     <a href="<% logout_url %>">log out</a>
  <% END %>

 <% IF session.logged_in %>
    <form id ="frm1" method ="POST" onsubmit ="return idCheck(this)" action="<% identry_url %>">
 <% ELSE %>
     <a href="<% login_url %>">login</a>                                                        <% END %> 
</div

<% IF msg %>
    <div class=flash> <% msg %> </div>
 <% END %>

  <% IF flash.error %>
      <div class=error> <% flash.error %> </div>
  <% END %>
 <% content %>
</div>


<p>&nbsp;<b>RackID</b> <input type="text" id="rack" size =8>&nbsp; <b>Tech Initial</b>&nbsp;
<input type="text" id="tech" size=3> &nbsp; </p>

<p>&nbsp;<b>V&nbsp; </b> <input type="text" id="id1"  size =8>&nbsp;
<input type="text" id="id2" size =8>&nbsp;
<input type ="text" id="id3" size =8>&nbsp;
<input type="text" id="id4" size =8>&nbsp;</p>


<p>&nbsp;<b>W</b> 
<input type="text" id="id5" size =8>&nbsp;
<input type="text" id="id6" size =8>&nbsp;
<input type="text" id="id7" size =8>&nbsp;
<input type="text" id="id8" size =8>&nbsp;
</p>

<p>&nbsp;<b>X&nbsp;</b>
<input type="text" id="id9" size =8>&nbsp;
<input type="text" id="id10" size =8>&nbsp;  
<input type="text" id="id11" size =8>&nbsp;
<input type="text" id="id12" size =8>&nbsp;
</p>

<p>&nbsp;<b>Y&nbsp;</b>
<input type="text" id="id13" size =8>&nbsp;
<input type="text" id="id14" size =8>&nbsp;
<input type="text" id="id15" size =8>&nbsp;
<input type="text" id="id16" size =8>&nbsp;
</p>

<p>&nbsp;<b>Z&nbsp;</b>
<input type="text" id="id17" size =8>&nbsp;
<input type="text" id="id18" size =8>&nbsp;
<input type="text" id="id19" size =8>&nbsp;
<input type="text" id="id20" size =8>&nbsp;
</p>



<input type="Submit" value="CheckID" name ="submit">
&nbsp;

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is my javascript function for the validation

```
function idCheck() {
    "use strict";

var chkstring, prime, flds, i, id, idlen, stub, rem;
chkstring = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ";
prime = chkstring.length;

 var flds =document.getElementById("frm1").querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]').;

 //Start Validation Loop
for (i = 2; i < flds.length; i++) {
    id = "";
    //get the value of the field
    id = flds[i].value;
    idlen = id.length;

    if (idlen !== 8) {
        //flds[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        alert("flds[i].value is not 8 charecters long");
        return false;

    }
    stub = id.substr(0, 7);
    if (stub === 0) {
        flds[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        return false;

    }
    stub = stub - 1;
    rem = stub % prime;
    if (chkstring.substr(rem, 1) !== id.substr(7, 1)) {
        flds[[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        return false;

    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: You probably have an error in your function. Try `flds[i]` instead of `flds.element[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

you should `return true` when form is valid as onSubmit  expecting this to proceed .

Answer (score 0):

This part of your validation function jumps out immediately as being wrong:

```
var flds =document.getElementById("frm1");

 //Start Validation Loop
for (i = 2; i < flds.length; i++) {
```

You're selecting the form element, then expecting it to have a `length` property greater than 2. That `i < flds.length` condition in the `for` loop needs to be changed to something else.

If you're looking to iterate over each of the inputs, you'd probably want something like this:

```
var flds = document.getElementById('frm1').querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');

for(i = 2; i < flds.length; i++) {
    id = flds[i].value;
    ...
```

The MDN entry for [Element.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelectorAll) has notes on browser compatibility, as well as more information about what it does.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I was under the impression that it is looping through  each text field. What I am trying to achieve is starting with the 3rd text field,loop through each element where type is 'text' do the validation. How could I acheive this?

Comment: @user2838042 Edited my answer to include a method with which you'd do that. If you want to loop through the text fields you need to select those directly.

Comment: Edited the JS, Still its submitting without going to the validation